# How to remove the shadow line from a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I added a `UINavigationController` to my `UIViewController` programmatically like following:

```
 UINavigationController * nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[ViewController fromStoryboardNamed:@"myVC"]];
```

and in the debug view hierarchy I see there is a view called `UIBackdropView` behind the `UINavigationBar` with gray color background. You can see that in the screenshot:

[image]

I tried to find it in the Documentation,but I couldn't find any.

Can we access this layer?

This causes a 1 pixel gray line to appear under the `UINavigationBar`. Is it possible to remove/hide the `_UIBackDropView`?

I tried to blend this 1 pixel line by adding a simple `UIView` with white background color under the `UINavigationBar` which covers this dark line,and it worked fine. I would like to know If there is a way to hide/remove the `BackdropView` instead of adding a `UIView` on top of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, this is only possible by setting the `shadowImage` of the navigationBar to an empty image, as has been mentioned in another answer. However, a closer look at the documentation, it is said:

> For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must also be set with the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method. If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless of the value of this property.

By using a custom background image, you would lose the blurred background translucency, which is likely not what you want.

The "hairline" is a UIImageView that is a subview of the navigation bar. You can find it and set it as hidden. This is what Apple does in their native calendar app, for example. Just iterate the subviews, and set the image view to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It is Apple private API. You can try to access it using superviews, or using `valueForKey`. However, I would not recommend using that. First of all, Apple may reject your application. Moreover, structure of all Apple built views may change at any time and your application may face issues. More information about **_UIBackdropView** you can find [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/_UIBackdropView.h).

The easiest and quickest solution to remove one pixel underline is this one:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

However it will remove blur, what is probably not what you want. You can use [UINavigationBar-Addition](https://github.com/samwize/UINavigationBar-Addition/) to easily remove hairline without affect your blur.

Comment: actually i want to remove the view just because it adds that 1 pixel line under the navigation bar

Comment: You can see how to hide it, it is a part of my answer and also added reference to a stackoverflow thread where this question was already asked.

Comment: @T_77 The shadow image is a different view.

Comment: @gontovnik Blur is disabled in your solution.

Comment: is it what creates the 1 pixel line under navigation bar @LeoNatan? How do I remove it?

Comment: @LeoNatan yes, I have added reference to another thread which shows how to keep blur.

Comment: @T_77 Update your question with what you want to do and I'll answer.