# Statusbar become transparent

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uinavigationbar

I need to remove the `UINavigationBar` shadow image.

[image: UINavigationBar contained line]

so I'm using the code below:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

It is working perfectly, but the area behind the status bar became transparent, like the image below:

[image: transparent area behind status bar]

and I don't need this. It should be white. What should I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the the answer:

It was just online statement, i.e:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

By adding this in `viewDidLoad` it started working as I wanted.
I got helped from this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796259/remove-shadow-line-below-navigation-bar-without-removing-bar-color`

Answer (score 1):

This occurs beause the navigation bar does not have a specified bar tint color. If you want to have a navigation bar with a bar tint color, you can set it in the IB inspector or programmatically:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide the status bar to remove it.

```
1.  Open Info.plist file
2.  Click + button to add new key
3.  "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" set to NO
```